# I left creme fraiche out of fridge for 2 hours it turned bad

Tags: food-safety, dairy, creme-fraiche

How long can you keep creme fraiche out of the fridge before it gets spoiled

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you would have about 2 hours of time in the "danger zone" before the food should be considered irretrievably unsafe.... obviously this was not the case for you.  If the ambient temperature is especially high, or the product was close to turning anyway, you might get less time.

Comment: The day was very cold - degrees with snow flakes.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: the FDA [link](http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/Transparency/Basics/ucm194302.htm), fwiw

Comment: It might go sour before it actually gets unsafe in terms of bacteria. 2 hours is just the margin for safety. It's generally the "good" bacteria that cause sourness in cultured products (i.e. the culture) but then again, if it's sour, why eat it even if it's still safe...